# ASP.NET Core 6 application with Entity Framework Core is performing a delete instead of update when saving object

Tags: entity-framework-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm experiencing an issue where upon trying to perform an update on my company object using Entity Framework Core, my object is being deleted. The create for the `Company` object is working as expected, and update elsewhere in my app is working as expected with no deletions.

The app is an  ASP.NET Core 6.0 Razor app. Target framework is .NET 6.0.

I did run a `get-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.10` in PMC. I'm using code-first and migrations.

The model I'm trying to update using EF Core is `Company` (rental company). Other model objects are:

```
PaymentType, State, Location, CarOrder, CompanyLocation
```

I've included what I think are relevant pages for troubleshooting: migration file, context file, the `Company` model and code behind for the razor page that does the update. I will add more code if anyone needs to see that.

I use both a model (`Company`) and a view model (`CompanyEditViewModel`) on the company update page code behind fyi.

Thanks

`Company.cs` (Company model)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace RentalCarSol.Models
{
    public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }     

        [Display(Name = "Rental Company Code")]
        [MaxLength(6)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Rental Company Code required")]
        public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Name is required")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }     

        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "State")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
        public int StateId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zip Code Format")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Zip Code is required")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        [MaxLength(14)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone is required")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }     

        [Display(Name = "Created By")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Updated By")]
        public string? UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Updated")]
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }   

        
        public virtual State State { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    }

    public enum CompanySearchTypeEnum
    {
        [Display(Name = "Company Code")]
        CompanyCode = 1,

        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        LName = 2,

        [Display(Name = "City")]
        City = 3
    }
}
```

`RentalCarContext.cs`:

```
#nullable disable
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RentalCarSol.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace RentalCarSol.Data
{
    public class RentalCarContext : DbContext
    {
        public RentalCarContext(DbContextOptions<RentalCarContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }       
        
        public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CarOrder> CarOrders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PaymentType> PaymentTypes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity("RentalCarSol.Models.Company", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("RentalCarSol.Models.State", "State")
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("StateId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.Navigation("State");
            });         

            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Locations)
                .WithMany(p => p.Companies)
                .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("CompanyLocations"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Companies)
                .WithMany(p => p.Locations)
                .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("CompanyLocations"));           
        }       
    }
}
```

`UpdateRentalCompany.cs` (Razor page code behind)

```
#nullable disable
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RentalCarSol.Models;
using RentalCarSol.ViewModels;
using RentalCarSol.Handlers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace RentalCarSol.Pages.Companies
{
    public class UpdateRentalCompanyModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RentalCarContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly QueryHandler _queryHandler;
        private MappingHandler _mappingHandler = new MappingHandler();

        public UpdateRentalCompanyModel(RentalCarSol.Data.RentalCarContext context, ILogger<UpdateRentalCompanyModel> logger, RentalCarSol.Handlers.QueryHandler queryHandler)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
            _queryHandler = queryHandler;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Company> CompanyList { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> StateList { get; set; }     
        [BindProperty]
        public CompanyEditViewModel SelectedCompanyVM { get; set; }
        public Company SelectedCompany { get; set; }
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Search By:")]
        public int SearchType { get; set; } = -1;
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; } = null;  

        public void OnGet(string CompanyCode = null)
        {       
            if (SearchType != -1 && SearchTerm != null)
            {
                CompanyList = _queryHandler.GetCompanyList(SearchType, SearchTerm);
            } 
            else
            {
                CompanyList = _queryHandler.GetCompanyList();
            }           

            if (CompanyList.Any())
            {
                if (CompanyCode != null && CompanyList.Any(c => c.CompanyCode == CompanyCode))
                {
                    var selectedCompanyID = _queryHandler.GetCompanyIDByCompanyCode(CompanyCode);
                    SelectedCompany = _context.Companies.Find(selectedCompanyID);
                }
                else
                {
                    SelectedCompany = CompanyList.First();
                }

                // Map the Company object to the view model for razor page
                SelectedCompanyVM = _mappingHandler.MapCompanyToCompanyEditVM(SelectedCompany);

                // Re-order the Companies by name
                SelectedCompanyVM.Companies.OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName);
            } 
            else
            {
                SelectedCompanyVM = new CompanyEditViewModel();
            }           

            StateList = _queryHandler.GetStateList();       
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                TempData["showToaster"] = "true";
                TempData["toastMessage"] = "Company Update NOT Successful!";
                foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
                {
                    foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
                    {                       
                        TempData["toastMessage"] += Environment.NewLine + error.ErrorMessage;
                    }
                }                   

                TempData["toastType"] = "warning";

                return RedirectToPage("Index", new { companyCode = SelectedCompanyVM.CompanyCode });
            }
                        
            SelectedCompany = _context.Companies.Find(SelectedCompanyVM.Id);

            SelectedCompany.CompanyName = SelectedCompanyVM.CompanyName;            
            SelectedCompany.StreetAddress = SelectedCompanyVM.StreetAddress;            
            SelectedCompany.City = SelectedCompanyVM.City;          
            SelectedCompany.StateId = SelectedCompanyVM.StateId;            
            SelectedCompany.ZipCode = SelectedCompanyVM.ZipCode;            
            SelectedCompany.PhoneNumber = SelectedCompanyVM.PhoneNumber;            
            SelectedCompany.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;          
            SelectedCompany.UpdatedBy = User?.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "DPSId").FirstOrDefault().Value;          
            
            _context.Attach(SelectedCompany).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {               
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();              
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!CompanyExists(SelectedCompany.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            TempData["showToaster"] = "true";
            TempData["toastMessage"] = "Company update successful!";

            return RedirectToPage("Index", new { companyCode = SelectedCompany.CompanyCode });
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostFilter()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("Index", new { searchterm = SearchTerm, searchtype = SearchType });
        }

        private bool CompanyExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Companies.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }   
    }
}
```

`20230320143408_Initialize.cs` (migration file)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace RentalCarSol.Migrations
{
    public partial class Initialize : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {        
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "PaymentTypes",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    PaymentTypeText = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    DisplayOrder = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_PaymentTypes", x => x.Id);
                });
            
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "States",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    StateCode = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(2)", maxLength: 2, nullable: false),
                    StateName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_States", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Locations",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    LocationCode = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(6)", maxLength: 6, nullable: false),
                    LocationName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    StreetAddress = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    MailingAddress = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: true),
                    City = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    StateId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ZipCode = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(10)", maxLength: 10, nullable: false),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(14)", maxLength: 14, nullable: false),
                    Contact = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: true),
                    CreatedBy = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    CreateDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                    UpdatedBy = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    UpdateDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: true),
                    IsAirport = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Locations", x => x.Id);                    
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Locations_States_StateId",
                        column: x => x.StateId,
                        principalTable: "States",
                        principalColumn: "Id");
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Companies",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    CompanyCode = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(6)", maxLength: 6, nullable: false),
                    CompanyName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    StreetAddress = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    City = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    StateId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ZipCode = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(10)", maxLength: 10, nullable: false),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(14)", maxLength: 14, nullable: false),
                    CreatedBy = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    CreateDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                    UpdatedBy = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    UpdateDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Companies", x => x.Id);                    
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Companies_States_StateId",
                        column: x => x.StateId,
                        principalTable: "States",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "CarOrders",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    CompanyId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    PaymentAmount = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18,2)", nullable: false),
                    PaymentName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    PaymentTypeId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    CheckNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(30)", maxLength: 30, nullable: true),
                    NumberOfCars = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    IsVoided = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: true),
                    CreatedBy = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    CreateDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                    UpdatedBy = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    UpdateDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_CarOrders", x => x.Id);
                    
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_CarOrders_Companies_Id",
                        column: x => x.CompanyId,
                        principalTable: "Companies",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_CarOrders_PaymentTypes_PaymentTypeId",
                        column: x => x.PaymentTypeId,
                        principalTable: "PaymentTypes",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                }); 

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "CompanyLocations",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    LocationsId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    CompaniesId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_CompanyLocations", x => new { x.CompaniesId, x.LocationsId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_CompanyLocations_Locations_LocationsId",
                        column: x => x.LocationsId,
                        principalTable: "Locations",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_CompanyLocations_Companies_CompaniesId",
                        column: x => x.CompaniesId,
                        principalTable: "Companies",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });            

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Companies_StateId",
                table: "Companies",
                column: "StateId");            

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_CarOrders_CompanyId",
                table: "CarOrders",
                column: "CompanyId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_CarOrders_PaymentTypeId",
                table: "CarOrders",
                column: "PaymentTypeId");                

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_CompanyLocations_CompaniesId",
                table: "CompanyLocations",
                column: "CompaniesId");            

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Companies_StateId",
                table: "Companies",
                column: "StateId");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "CompanyLocations");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "CarOrders");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Locations");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Companies");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "PaymentTypes");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "States");
        }
    }
}
```

I have another page (Location model update) in this app that is coded the same way as I coded the update for the Company object and that update is not performing a delete.

Could it have something to do with cascade delete? I don't want any cascade delete behavior in the app. I see "onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade" instances in the migration file that was generated. As an aside, I would like to prevent all cascade delete in the entire app.

Comment: I'm not sure you should be attempting to re-attach `SelectedCompany` -> `_context.Attach(SelectedCompany)` the entity wshould already be attached and the state be updated to modified autoimagically.

Comment: Please provide a minimalistic code example which reproduces your issues; don't expect others to plough themselves through your codebase.

Also check what's in the ChangeTracker before a SaveChanges is executed.

Comment: Have you checked what SQL command is being executed?